# How set PopupWindow above anchor with height=WRAP_CONTENT (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a sample code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.pop, null));
    pw.setHeight(500); //any positive value
    pw.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pw.showAsDropDown(findViewById(R.id.btn));
}
```

But in 6.0 PopupWindow.setWindowLayoutMode() is deprecated, and I have: [<6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEQzO.png) and [6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIqPe.png). I think in 6.0 different "isAbove" calculation.

How in 6.0 realize old behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android Developer Document setWindowLayoutMode() is deprecated in 23..instead of setWindowLayoutMode() you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setWindowLayoutMode(int,%20int)) and serach for **setWindowLayoutMode()** key word you will get the all information.

Comment: This should be comment not answer!

Comment: I know about deprecation, but i dont know how I must change my code for correct calculation above placement. Problem showed when I set height = WRAP_CONTENT (with setHeight or setWindowLayoutMode).